# Constant column alongside aggregate columns in GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate

Let's say I have

```
id                shop           item       price
===============================================
1                 A              A1         11
1                 A              A2         12
3                 B              B1         21 
4                 B              B2         22
```

and I would want to do a `GROUP BY shop` plus putting a constant column to get

```
    shop            total_price     const
    ===============================================
    A                 23              x  
    B                 43              x
```

How would I include the const column, while GROUP BY dictates that the column must be either the group item or aggregate function ?

Comment: Although I don't think you actually need it here, you can always wrap a dummy function like `min()` around the value in order to satisfy a picky (and stupid) system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to aggregate for a constant value:

```
with test(id, shop, item, price)
as (
    select 1,'A', 'A1',11 from dual union all
    select 1,'A', 'A2',12 from dual union all
    select 3,'B', 'B1',21  from dual union all
    select 4,'B', 'B2',22 from dual
)
select shop, sum(price) as total_price, 'x' as const
from test
group by shop
```

Comment: need to remove the "from dual" from the script, then it runs w/o any schema requirement